# Dynamically index into Python dictionary based on function parameters

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I'm building a function that indexes into a Python dictionary nested inside a list. The user knows what the dictionary looks like in advance. This is what it looks like so far:

```
def dict_idx(arr: list, subkey: str) -> list:
    for i in arr:
        i[subkey] = i[subkey].replace("_", " ")
    return arr
```

I would like to make the `subkey` parameter a *list* of strings, and to index into the dictionary depending like this.  So for instance, if I pass this function a `subkey` value of ['user','location'], it would index into the array like follows:

```
    for i in arr:
        i['user']['location'] = i['user']['location'].replace("_", " ")
```

Is this possible (short of converting the list into a string of dictionary indexes and running eval() on that string)?

Comment: loop over the keys and index into it?

Comment: suppose `data = {<some nested dict>}` and `keys = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']` then to retreive, you can do something like `val = data` then `for key in keys: val = val[key]` etc etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the same approach as alani, although, with some style differences I would humbly suggest:

```
from operator import getitem
from functools import reduce

def retrieve_nested(dictionary, keys):
    return reduce(getitem, keys, dictionary)

def dict_idx(data: list[dict], subkeys: list[str]) -> None:
    *subkeys, lastkey = subkeys
    for d in data:
        value = retrieve_nested(d, subkeys)
        value[lastkey] = value[lastkey].replace("_", " ")
```

Or perhaps, dispense with the helper function:

```
from operator import getitem
from functools import reduce


def dict_idx(data: list[dict], subkeys: list[str]) -> None:
    *subkeys, lastkey = subkeys
    for d in data:
        value = reduce(getitem, d, subkeys)
        value[lastkey] = value[lastkey].replace("_", " ")
```

Comment: Nice use of `reduce`.

Answer (score 4):

You can loop over all except one of the keys (`subkey[:-1]`), to access deeper and deeper sub-dictionaries, then index using the last key (`subkey[-1]`) for the assignment statement at the end.

Something like this:

```
def dict_idx(arr: list, subkey: list):
    for d in arr:
        for key in subkey[:-1]:
            d = d[key]
        lastkey = subkey[-1]
        d[lastkey] = d[lastkey].replace("_", " ")


arr = [{'user': {'location': 'some_where'},
        'foo': 2},
       {'user': {'location': 'some_where_else'},
        'bar': 3}]

subkey = ['user', 'location']

dict_idx(arr, subkey)

print(arr)
```

gives:

```
[{'user': {'location': 'some where'}, 'foo': 2}, {'user': {'location': 'some where else'}, 'bar': 3}]
```

Note that the function in this suggested code does not return the list, simply modifies it in place (or more specifically, modifies elements of inner data items). It is generally a bad idea for a function to *both* do an in-place modification and also return the value, because it can lead to confusion as to the purpose of the function.

---

By the way, you might also want to consider what should happen if the dictionaries do *not* contain the relevant keys. In the above code, it would raise an `KeyError` exception. If you would prefer to silently ignore these errors, you could put the code inside the outer `for` loop into `try` - `except` block, for example as follows:

```
def dict_idx(arr: list, subkey: list):
    for d in arr:
        try:
            for key in subkey[:-1]:
                d = d[key]
            lastkey = subkey[-1]
            d[lastkey] = d[lastkey].replace("_", " ")
        except KeyError:
            continue
```

Comment: a tip: `*subkey, last_key = subkey` then just `for key in subkey: ...` and finally, `d[last_key] = d[last_key].replace("_", " ")` essentially equivalent to what you have, but IMO cleaner

Comment: And I might refactor out a helper function, `def retrieve_nested` then it's just `*subkey, key = subkey` then `d = retreive_nested(subkey)` etc etc

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Good idea. Maybe you could post another answer?

Comment: sure, I can do that real quick